# Mockito testing in MVP kotlin - However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock exception

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I have developed an application with Kotlin and MVP architecture.I want to do unit testing using Mockito but unable to achieve it.I'm getting "However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock exception".
In my application i have used 5 different classes.

1. View - Interface
2. Intractor - Interface
3. IntractorImpl - Class
4. Presenter - Interfacce
5. PresenterImpl - Class

**View:-** It contain all methods required for to communicate activity/fragment.

**Intractor:-** It contain the result interface methods.

**IntractorImpl :-** It contain database/server logic, it will implemented from Intractor

**Presenter :-** It contain methods to access the IntractorImpl class

**PresenterImpl :-** It is implemented from Presenter and Intractor result methods

This architecture which i followed for implementing, now to implement the Mockito i'm getting confusion and as per the articles i found in google if i try to implement i'm getting **"However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock exception"**

For mockito i have used following imports

```
 //Mockito
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.24.5"
```

Please if anyone knows anything,help me out. First time i'm using Mokito.
If anyone need more information i can post it. Following is my code

```
class EventTest {
    @Mock
    val homeActivity = HomeActivity()
    lateinit var eventView: HomeView
    lateinit var eventInteractorImpl: HomeInteractorImpl
    lateinit var eventPresenter: HomePresenter
    lateinit var eventInteractor: HomeInteractor.OnEventsReceivedListener
    @Before
    fun setUpEventPresenter() {
        eventView = mock(HomeView::class.java)
        eventInteractorImpl = mock(HomeInteractorImpl::class.java)
        eventPresenter = HomePresenterImpl(eventView, eventInteractorImpl)
        eventInteractor = mock(HomeInteractor.OnEventsReceivedListener::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun startEventTest() {
        val testEvents = Event(
            "1",
            "Test",
            "Next week we have the vacation planing in Vizag",
            "This is for test",
            "1",
            "01-10-2019",
            "26-09-2019",
            "8.00",
            "10.47",
            "",
            true
        )
        val events: ArrayList<Event> = ArrayList<Event>()
        events.add(testEvents)
        eventPresenter.getEventsList(homeActivity)
        verify(eventView).showProgress()
        verify(eventView).showEvents(events)
        verify(eventView).hideProgress()
    }

}
```

If i put `verify(eventView).showProgress()` no exception is coming.

```
 override fun getEventsList(context: Context) {
    homeView.showProgress()
    homeInteractor.getEvents(context, this)
}
```

In getEvents() method we are calling server/local database, for Server we are using Retrofit.

Comment: Can you add code of getEventsList function?

Comment: @NatigBabayev in getEventsList function i'm calling Intractor method for getting data from server/local database

Comment: @NatigBabayev my application MVP is almost similar to this https://medium.com/@MiBLT/refactoring-to-mvp-b504a3774ffd

Comment: Without posting `getEventsList()` I don't think we can provide any help regarding why test is breaking. Also, I have passed free article limit in medium, so, I cannot check that post :D You can post the code here.

Comment: @I have updated the code please check once.

Comment: Does homeInteractor.getEvents(context, this) call eventView also? If yes, can you add code?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and explanation you gave in comments, the error message you're getting is correct because you're invoking mock `interactor` which cannot invoke other view functions.

Therefore, only thing you should verify in `startEventTest()` is `verify(eventView).showProgress()` and     `verify(eventInteractorImpl).getEvents(any(), any())`:

```
@Test
fun startEventTest() {
    val testEvents = Event(
        "1",
        "Test",
        "Next week we have the vacation planing in Vizag",
        "This is for test",
        "1",
        "01-10-2019",
        "26-09-2019",
        "8.00",
        "10.47",
        "",
        true
    )
    val events: ArrayList<Event> = ArrayList<Event>()
    events.add(testEvents)
    eventPresenter.getEventsList(homeActivity)
    verify(eventView).showProgress()
    verify(eventInteractorImpl).getEvents(any(), any())
}
```

If you still want to test `verify(eventView).showEvents(events)` and `verify(eventView).hideProgress()`, instead of mocking interactor, you should create instance of it.

Comment: I had try this one still unable to do it "any() must not be null" exception is coming

Comment: You can use mockito kotlin then you shouldn’t get such errors